# Display images in a popup/ new tab/window when View button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Here the code I have tried. *val is a variable and it `theFunction()` will be called for multiple images.

```
<th style="color:#cc0000">Fail</th><td><a href="javascript:void();" id="img8" class="hide\  value="show my Image" onclick="return theFunction(8);">view</a>

<img id="myimage8" class="hide" src="image1.jpg"  alt="check image path" width="100px" height="100px">

<img id="myimage_8" class="hide" src="image2.jpg" alt="check image path" width="100px" height="100px"></td>
<script>
function theFunction(val) {
  obj0=document.getElementById('img'.concat(val)); 
  obj1 = document.getElementById('myimage'.concat(val));
  obj2 = document.getElementById('myimage_'.concat(+val));
  obj1.className=='hide'? (obj1.className='',this.value='hide my Image'): (obj1.className='hide',this.value='show my Image'); 
  obj2.className=='hide'? (obj2.className='',this.value='hide my Image'): (obj2.className='hide',this.value='show my Image');
  return true;
}
window.addEventListener? window.addEventListener('load',theFunction,false): window.attachEvent('onload',theFunction); 
</script>
```

**The actual result:**

the images are displayed just after 'view' button when clicked

**Expected:**

the images are to be displayed in a popup window.

I tried, `target="_blank"` but it is not working. Someone suggested to use `windows.open()`, but I don't know how to call it. Can someone help me out to resolve this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.open to open a new URL. If your image is available via a URL that is accessible to consumers, you can just do:

```
window.open(image-url)
```

When a user clicks it, it will open your image on a new window

There is one more better option though. I suggest you display the image in a popup without any redirections. You can easily use bootstrap model popup for that. See [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/) for reference.

Comment: We are not passing image in url it is passed as an argument.

Comment: @RSKRao If you want to open image in a new tab, you can simply for the url as your-domain/image-name and pass it. Your src attribute is nothing but the url/location of the image to render from

Comment: onclick=window.open(return theFunction(8))--> is this the way to call?

Comment: @RSKRao If you have to do it like this, let thefunction return the URL string instead of true. Then do onclick="window.open(theFunction(8))". Another option is  to call window.open from inside your theFunction